# ERROR: cannot launch node of type [footstep_planner/footstep_planner_node] (updated)

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,
i want to run "footstep_planner_complete.launch" node in humanoid_navigation stack, but this error appears into my terminal:
"ERROR: cannot launch node of type [footstep_planner/footstep_planner_node]: can't locate node [footstep_planner_node] in package [footstep_planner]"
rviz window opens but the planner does not work due to that error.

besides my ros version is Groovy!.

***Error On Groovy***
rosmake humanoid_navigation

[rosmake ] rosmake starting...
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['humanoid_navigation']
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/hafez/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20131126-194019
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['humanoid_navigation'] to:
['hrl_kinematics', 'humanoid_localization', 'gridmap_2d', 'footstep_planner']
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> catkin [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< catkin ROS_NOBUILD in package catkin
No Makefile in package catkin
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> genmsg [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< genmsg ROS_NOBUILD in package genmsg
No Makefile in package genmsg
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> genlisp [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< genlisp ROS_NOBUILD in package genlisp
No Makefile in package genlisp
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> genpy [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< genpy ROS_NOBUILD in package genpy
No Makefile in package genpy
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> gencpp [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< gencpp ROS_NOBUILD in package gencpp                                                                                 [ 1 Active 4/71 Complete ]
No Makefile in package gencpp
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> cpp_common [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> message_generation [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rospack [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< message_generation ROS_NOBUILD in package message_generation
No Makefile in package message_generation
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< cpp_common ROS_NOBUILD in package cpp_common
No Makefile in package cpp_common
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> console_bridge [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rostime [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rospack ROS_NOBUILD in package rospack
No Makefile in package rospack
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< roslang ROS_NOBUILD in package roslang
No Makefile in package roslang
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> xmlrpcpp [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< console_bridge ROS_NOBUILD in package console_bridge
No Makefile in package console_bridge
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> urdfdom_headers [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rostime ROS_NOBUILD in package rostime
No Makefile in package rostime
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roscpp_traits [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< xmlrpcpp ROS_NOBUILD in package xmlrpcpp
No Makefile in package xmlrpcpp
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> orocos_kdl [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< roslib ROS_NOBUILD in package roslib
No Makefile in package roslib
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosunit [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< urdfdom_headers ROS_NOBUILD in package urdfdom_headers
No Makefile in package urdfdom_headers
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roscpp_traits ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp_traits
No Makefile in package roscpp_traits
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> urdfdom [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roscpp_serialization [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< orocos_kdl ROS_NOBUILD in package orocos_kdl
No Makefile in package orocos_kdl
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosunit ROS_NOBUILD in package rosunit
No Makefile in package rosunit
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosgraph [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roscpp_serialization ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp_serialization
No Makefile in package roscpp_serialization
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> message_runtime [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosgraph ROS_NOBUILD in package rosgraph
No Makefile in package rosgraph
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosparam [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< urdfdom ROS_NOBUILD in package urdfdom
No Makefile in package urdfdom
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosmaster [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosconsole ROS_NOBUILD in package rosconsole
No Makefile in package rosconsole
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< message_runtime ROS_NOBUILD in package message_runtime
No Makefile in package message_runtime
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosmaster ROS_NOBUILD in package rosmaster
No Makefile in package rosmaster
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosparam ROS_NOBUILD in package rosparam
No Makefile in package rosparam
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosclean [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosconsole_bridge [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> angles [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< std_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package std_msgs
No Makefile in package std_msgs
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosgraph_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosconsole_bridge ROS_NOBUILD in package rosconsole_bridge
No Makefile in package rosconsole_bridge
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> geometry_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosclean ROS_NOBUILD in package rosclean
No Makefile in package rosclean
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosgraph_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package rosgraph_msgs
No Makefile in package rosgraph_msgs
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> class_loader [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< angles ROS_NOBUILD in package angles
No Makefile in package angles
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< geometry_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package geometry_msgs
No Makefile in package geometry_msgs
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rospy [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> sensor_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< class_loader ROS_NOBUILD in package class_loader
No Makefile in package class_loader
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> kdl_conversions [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roscpp ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp
No Makefile in package roscpp
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rospy ROS_NOBUILD in package rospy
No Makefile in package rospy
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> collada_parser [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< sensor_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package sensor_msgs
No Makefile in package sensor_msgs
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosout [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> visualization_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< kdl_conversions ROS_NOBUILD in package kdl_conversions
No Makefile in package kdl_conversions
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< visualization_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package visualization_msgs
No Makefile in package visualization_msgs
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< collada_parser ROS_NOBUILD in package collada_parser
No Makefile in package collada_parser
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> pluginlib [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> smclib [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> urdf [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< urdf ROS_NOBUILD in package urdf
No Makefile in package urdf
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosout ROS_NOBUILD in package rosout
No Makefile in package rosout
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> roslaunch [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> kdl_parser [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< smclib ROS_NOBUILD in package smclib
No Makefile in package smclib
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< pluginlib ROS_NOBUILD in package pluginlib
No Makefile in package pluginlib
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> bond [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> pcl_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< roslaunch ROS_NOBUILD in package roslaunch
No Makefile in package roslaunch
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rostest [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< kdl_parser ROS_NOBUILD in package kdl_parser
No Makefile in package kdl_parser
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> flann [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< bond ROS_NOBUILD in package bond
No Makefile in package bond
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> bondcpp [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< flann ROS_NOBUILD in package flann
No Makefile in package flann
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rostest ROS_NOBUILD in package rostest
No Makefile in package rostest
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> hrl_kinematics [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> message_filters [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< pcl_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package pcl_msgs
No Makefile in package pcl_msgs
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< bondcpp ROS_NOBUILD in package bondcpp
No Makefile in package bondcpp
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> topic_tools [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> nodelet [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< topic_tools ROS_NOBUILD in package topic_tools sec ] [ topic_tools: 0.0 sec ] [ nodelet: 0.0 sec ]                  [ 4 Active 48/71 Complete ]
No Makefile in package topic_tools
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosbag [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< message_filters ROS_NOBUILD in package message_filters
No Makefile in package message_filters
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< nodelet ROS_NOBUILD in package nodelet
No Makefile in package nodelet
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> tf [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosbag ROS_NOBUILD in package rosbag
No Makefile in package rosbag
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> actionlib_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosmsg [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< tf ROS_NOBUILD in package tf
No Makefile in package tf
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> tf_conversions [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosmsg ROS_NOBUILD in package rosmsg
No Makefile in package rosmsg
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< actionlib_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package actionlib_msgs
No Makefile in package actionlib_msgs
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< tf_conversions ROS_NOBUILD in package tf_conversions
No Makefile in package tf_conversions
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> robot_state_publisher [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> pcl [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosservice [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< pcl ROS_NOBUILD in package pcl
No Makefile in package pcl
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> actionlib [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< robot_state_publisher ROS_NOBUILD in package robot_state_publisher
No Makefile in package robot_state_publisher
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> humanoid_nav_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosservice ROS_NOBUILD in package rosservice
No Makefile in package rosservice
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> dynamic_reconfigure [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< actionlib ROS_NOBUILD in package actionlib
No Makefile in package actionlib
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> nav_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< humanoid_nav_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package humanoid_nav_msgs
No Makefile in package humanoid_nav_msgs
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> std_srvs [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< dynamic_reconfigure ROS_NOBUILD in package dynamic_reconfigure
No Makefile in package dynamic_reconfigure
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> nodelet_topic_tools [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< std_srvs ROS_NOBUILD in package std_srvs
No Makefile in package std_srvs
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< nav_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package nav_msgs
No Makefile in package nav_msgs
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> gridmap_2d [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> map_server [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< nodelet_topic_tools ROS_NOBUILD in package nodelet_topic_tools
No Makefile in package nodelet_topic_tools
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> pcl_ros [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< pcl_ros ROS_NOBUILD in package pcl_ros
No Makefile in package pcl_ros
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> humanoid_localization [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< map_server ROS_NOBUILD in package map_server
[ rosmake ] All 21 linesrl_kinematics: 0.4 sec ] [ gridmap_2d: 0.4 sec ] [ humanoid_localization: 0.4 sec ]                                  [ 3 Active 67/71 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
mkdir -p bin
cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
[rosbuild] Building package humanoid_localization
Failed to invoke /opt/ros/groovy/bin/rospack deps-manifests humanoid_localization
[rospack] Error: package/stack 'humanoid_localization' depends on non-existent package 'octomap_msgs' and rosdep claims that it is not a system dependency. Check the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH or try calling 'rosdep update'

CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:129 (message):

```
Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package
'humanoid_localization'.  Look above for errors from rospack itself.
Aborting.  Please fix the broken dependency!
```

Call Stack (most recent call first):
/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:203 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack)
CMakeLists.txt:13 (rosbuild_init)

### -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

[ rosmake ] Output from build of package humanoid_localization written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/hafez/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20131126-194019/humanoid_localization/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< humanoid_localization [FAIL] [ 0.38 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package humanoid_localization.
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] All 21 linesrl_kinematics: 0.5 sec ] [ gridmap_2d: 0.5 sec ]                                                                     [ 2 Active 67/71 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
mkdir -p bin
cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
[rosbuild] Building package hrl_kinematics
Failed to invoke /opt/ros/groovy/bin/rospack deps-manifests hrl_kinematics
[rospack] Error: package/stack 'hrl_kinematics' depends on non-existent package 'geometric_shapes' and rosdep claims that it is not a system dependency. Check the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH or try calling 'rosdep update'

CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:129 (message):

```
Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package 'hrl_kinematics'.
Look above for errors from rospack itself.  Aborting.  Please fix the
broken dependency!
```

Call Stack (most recent call first):
/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:203 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack)
CMakeLists.txt:12 (rosbuild_init)

### -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

[ rosmake ] Output from build of package hrl_kinematics written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/hafez/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20131126-194019/hrl_kinematics/build_output.log
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< hrl_kinematics [FAIL] [ 0.51 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package hrl_kinematics.
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< gridmap_2d [PASS] [ 2.82 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] Results:
[ rosmake ] Built 70 packages with 2 failures.
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory
[ rosmake ] /home/hafez/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20131126-194019

any idea?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/104691/error:-cannot-launch-node-of-type-%5Bfootstep_planner/footstep_planner_node%5D-(updated)/) by [Hafez Farazi](https://answers.ros.org/users/8891/hafez-farazi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-11-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

it seems that Some Dependencies were missing and those packages were not install by default!

this is My Solution:

sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-octomap*

sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-geometr*

sudo apt-get install pkg*

sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev

sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-sbpl

after all, because installing libcul4-gnutls-dev automatically remove rviz !!!(WHY ON EARTH??):

sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-desktop-full

now :

roslaunch footstep_planner footstep_planner_complete.launch

---

Originally posted by [Hafez Farazi](https://answers.ros.org/users/8891/hafez-farazi/) with karma: 16 on 2013-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1